# Will a toilet crack if used as a fire pit?

Tags: toilet, fire-hazard, fire, porcelain, fire-pit

I am doing some last minute Halloween preparation. I would like to have a small fire going in an above-grade fire pit. Since its Halloween, I would like to get an old toilet and light my fire in that instead of a boring steel fire bowl.

Will a toilet hold up to the heat of a fire?

I know the ceramic can handle the heat. I'm worried about shattering if the temperature differential if the inside has fire but its cool and rainy outside. My primary concern is safety, I do not want shards of ceramic ruining a holiday.

Comment: It can handle the temps but an uninstalled toilet isn't very stable, I wouldn't want a raging fire in a loose toilet.   And I hope this will be in a fenced yard, not where unknown kids will be running around.

Comment: Decorate the toilet other ways with lights, fake fire, monsters, and even mock bodily fluids.  With children, alcohol, crowds, and a lot of other things demanding your attention, Halloween isn't the best time for an open fire.  And if you *will* be sitting attentively around the fire with a bunch of people who appreciate that, I don't see how doing it in a toilet will enhance the experience.  Try this: Feed a smoke machine into the drain outlet so smoke comes pouring out the bowl, and shine a green laser onto the area around it.  It will look like you have primordial ooze flowing out.

Comment: It's not shards of ceramic i'd be worried about, those are like brick chunks and are mostly harmless; it's shards of glaze (basically glass) I would worry about. It shouldn't shatter, you might see the glaze crack and spiderweb, but as long as the ceramic is intact, and porcelain specifically can take more heat than about anything, the glaze is pretty well stuck to it.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd simply get a stainless steel basin in about the right size that'll fit inside the toilet bowl (a round toilet bowl will probably work better for this than an elongated) and build the fire in that.

Comment: Good idea. That would avoid direct exposure of the heat to the ceramic. There would still be a temperature differential but should be a good airgap around the bowl.

Comment: Maybe you could also lay some fiber insulation around the bowl (and/or stuff the troilet trap).  Might also help stabilize it.

Comment: The toilet bowl was glazed and fired at around 1200C, far above the temperature of any fire you are going to have. Having a thermal gradient may well be a problem though.